# Angular (4): @Output to parent component through routerLink

Tags: angular

I am trying to emit an event from one of my child component through a `router-outlet` to a `top-navi` component class method. The structure of the `main.component.html` looks something like this:

```
<top-navi></top-navi>
<router-outlet (notify)="onNotify($event)"></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

`main.component.ts` class:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    translate.use('en');
  }

  public onNotify(value: boolean):void {
    console.log('event arrived:' + value);
  }
}
```

Child `component.ts` class looks something like this:

```
export class WelcomeWizardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() notify = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  public integrationPartnerDocStepActive = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public assignDocumentationTrack() {
    if (this.type == 'integrationPartner') {
      this.integrationPartnerDocStepActive = true;
      this.notify.emit(this.integrationPartnerDocStepActive);
    }
  }
}
```

I know that even is being emitted, but it never gets to `main.component.ts` Nothing happens. Is there a possibility to pass emitted events through `router-outlet`?

Comment: what is the use case for this , may be there is some other way too

Comment: @RahulSingh depending upon the value of `this.integrationPartnerDocStepActive` I want to manipulate the top-navi: change it to another one.

Comment: using a shared service might help in this case , do they have a parent child relation ship . i guess they dont as it is not nested. that is the reason the output dosent work , you need [shared services](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Comment: @RahulSingh I am not sure shared services will work. How will the `top-navi` component know when the data in the component through `router-outlet` changes?

Comment: when the component loads in the router outlet you will fire the inner components constructor or ngOnInit make changes there and that will save data in a subject in service which will emit a event notifying the nav comp, check the link

Comment: @RahulSingh this won't work for me because the value of that variable changes `after` the component has been loaded with user form manipulations. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: then update the service after the user changes the form , its at your wish when you want to change the subject in the service

Comment: @RahulSingh thanks, you're probably correct. If you want some extra points, just provide a sample of shared service as an answer and I can accept it ;)

Comment: no thanks not here for points glad it helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155923/discussion-between-deniss-m-and-rahul-singh).